# Динамические имена переменных

Tags: qmake

Пишу функцию qmake

```
defineTest(addLibraryHeaders){
   LIB_NAME = $$1
   isEmpty(LIB_NAME){
      warning(empty argument: 1)
      return (false)
   }

   #LIB_PATH = $${$${LIB_NAME}_PATH} - так не работает
   LIB_PATH = .
   message($$LIB_PATH)
   INCLUDEPATH += $${LIB_PATH}/include
   return(true)
}
```

в mkspec файлах определены переменные типа [NAME]_PATH 
Хотелось бы передавать имя либы чтобы генерировалось динамическое имя переменой, как в php.

```
addLibraryHeaders(BOOST) -> LIB_PATH = $$BOOST_PATH
addLibraryHeaders(AV) -> LIB_PATH = $$AV_PATH
```

Копал в сторону eval, но не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нагуглил решение

```
defineTest(addLibraryHeaders){
    LIB_NAME = $$1
    isEmpty(LIB_NAME){
        warning(empty 1 arg)
        return (false)
    }

    #нужно "эскейпить" $
    eval(LIB_PATH = \$\$$${LIB_NAME}_PATH)

    message($$LIB_PATH)

    INCLUDEPATH += $${LIB_PATH}/include
    export(INCLUDEPATH)
    return(true)
}
```